# Sympy simplifying sums based on free parameters

Tags: sympy

I have a sympy sum:

```
import sympy

x = sympy.IndexedBase('x')
n = sympy.symbols('n')
i = sympy.symbols('i', cls=sympy.Idx)

my_sum = sympy.summation(x[i], (i,1,n))
```

In my various calculations and whatnot, I sometimes end up with nested sums.  Sometimes, these sums have "free variables", and sometimes not.  For example, I might end up with the following:

```
my_double_sum = sympy.summation(my_sum, (i,1,n))
```

Now, since `my_sum` doesn't have a "free" `i` from the persepective of the outer sum, then this should simplify to:

```
n*Sum(x[i], (i, 1, n))
```

However, `sympy.simplify(my_double_sum)` gives:

```
Sum(x[i], (i, 1, n), (i, 1, n))
```

How can I make `sympy` simplify summations intelligently with respect to the free summand indices?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior did look a bit weird. Here is why it happens (and see the bottom for what is a bug and what is not).

---

First, [`summation`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/concrete/summations.py) is just a syntactic sugar to creating a `Sum` and running `.doit()`. `Sum`'s `doit` uses among the rest [`eval_sum`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/concrete/summations.py), which extracts the limit bounds when the limit variable is not a free variable of the function, and a simple checks shows that indeed **this should hold here!** (and as you showed, it doesn't):

```
>>> i in my_sum.free_symbols
False
```

so I did a little digging into the `summation` module.

Now, [`Sum`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/concrete/summations.py) has a parent called [`AddWithLimits`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/concrete/expr_with_limits.py). In its class creator, it uses the **[`_common_new`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/concrete/expr_with_limits.py) function that denests the function it receives**.

This turns `Sum(Sum(x[i], (i, 1, n)), (i, 1, n))` into `Sum(x[i], (i, 1, n), (i, 1, n))` (way before `doit` is invoked), so the internal function is `x[i]` and not the `Sum` object you defined in `my_sum` (which doesn't pop up at first sight), **so the limit variable actually is a free variable of the function**.

---

**I tried to manually cancel the denesting**, commenting the three lines under the comment `# denest any nested calls`, and indeed, I received

```
n*Sum(x[i], (i, 1, n))
```

Of course, simply changing that would probably hurt other parts of the code, since the denesting is assumed in many other `ExprWithLimits` functions. **Whether this is an intended behvior can be argued in favor**, but if you think it should be covered, it probably has to be specified explicitly inside `eval_sum` as a special case.

---

However, I would expect summation with another variable to be simplified normally, like

```
summation(x[i], (i, 1, n), (j, 1, n))
```

which does not. This, I suspect, is **more of an intended behavior** (which is caused because the first iteration over `eval_sum` returns `None`, so it skips the `j` symbol expansion).

Comment: So, do you recommend building my `Sum`s in some other way to obtain the desired behavior?

Comment: @Scott I added a footnote regarding a solution. I would have expected `summation(x[i], (i, 1, n), (j, 1, n))` (another variable) to work properly for you, but it doesn't, which I suspect is the real problem. I think the latter should be reported to `sympy` as an issue.

Comment: @Scott note that the simplification mechanism is simply a bunch of implemented heuristics. `sympy` has 200 open issues on `simplify` alone right now.